# How can I make an optional argument in my custom function in PHP?

Tags: php, function

For example, here's a quick dummy function that sums it up:

```
function dummy_func($optional)
{
    if (!isset($optional)
    {
        $optional = "World!";
    }
    $output = "Hello " . $optional;
    return $output;
}
```

However, if I run this, I get an E_WARNING for a missing argument. How can I set it up so it doesn't flag an error?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Optional arguments need to be given a default value. Instead of checking `isset` on the argument, just give it the value you want it to have if not given:

```
function dummy_func($optional = "World!")
{
    $output = "Hello " . $optional;
    return $output;
}
```

See the page on [Function arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php) in the manual (particularly the [Default argument values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default) section).

Answer (score 9):

You can do that by making `$optional` argument take default value of `"World!"`:

```
function dummy_func($optional="World!")
{
    $output = "Hello " . $optional;
    return $output;
}
```

Now when calling the function if you don't provide any argument, `$optional` will take the default value but if you pass an argument, `$optional` will take the value passed.

Example:

```
echo dummy_func();      // makes use of default value...prints Hello World!
echo dummy_func('foo!'); // makes use of argument passed...prints Hello foo!
```

Comment: I would like to know why his was downvoted, as well. I upvoted it, because it works and is actually the same as the accepted answer, I just couldn't accept both.