# If isset function variable paramenters php

Tags: php, if-statement, isset

I have this function

```json
    private static function applayPrice($objProduct, Product $product, $applay_price, $applay_old_price)
    {}
```

The problem is that sometimes the variable `Product $product` doesn't exist and this gives me an error.

I would like to do a kind of if isset and if it doesn't exist just apply the `$product` variable

I'm new to programming I hope I don't offend anyone with this question hehe
To explain myself better, I would like it to look like this, any ideas?

```json
    private static function applayPrice($objProduct, if( isset( Product $product ) ) {Product $product}else{$product}, $applay_price, $applay_old_price)
    {}
```

I know that this cannot be done but more or less the idea is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to do this:

```
    private static function applayPrice($objProduct, Product $product = NULL, $applay_price, $applay_old_price)
    {}
```

This simply means if the $product is not set, then it will be **NULL**.

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856115/how-can-i-make-an-optional-argument-in-my-custom-function-in-php) too.

Comment: instead of null could you put another variable?

Comment: @Club Yes of course, please check the link attached to the answer.